# Virtualizing Windows ARM Edition on an ARM Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, arm

Is it possible to virtualize the ARM edition of Windows on an ARM Linux machine, and if so how would this be accomplished. I've tried emulating Windows in QEMU, but it's far too slow. The host OS is ubuntu.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Do a web search on 'Windows ARM virtual image'